# Alignment issue with datatables in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Please check the following and jsfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ControllersDataTable').dataTable({
            "scrollY": "200px",
            "paging": false
        });
    });
```

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/b1yehpcv/)**

data table headers are not aligned on resize.
Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Is anyone out can help me?

Answer (score 2):

It is working now on resize, check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b1yehpcv/6/

You need to use iDisplayLength, see here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ControllersDataTable').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 5
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't want paging, your answer added paging and also removed scrolling

Comment: Waiting for your reply